# files are being deleted from output directory when the program starts

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a solution which comprises two project; proj1 and proj2, proj1 is a class library project which has 4 files that has the property of 'copy to output directory' set to  'copy always'.

proj2 has a dependency on proj1 and it is the startup project of the solution.
when I rebuild the solution all the 4 files are copied to the output directory of proj2, but for some wierd reason when I press Debug and the program starts , the 4 files are then immediately being deleted from the output directory. what might be the cause ?

Comment: AFAIK  your program or a postbuild action.

Comment: i dont have anything that might cause it in my postbuild events, just basic copy commands to create directories in my output directory